# Span Multiple Grid Cells In Tailwind CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind CSS and am trying to build a grid that certain cell contents span multiple cells while other items stay in the single cell.  In the code below, I try to show what I am trying to accomplish.  I know my col-span-2 class is not doing anything, but I put it there to indicate what I wish I could do.  I want all cells to be the same width (I just want some cell content to span over the dividers).  Do I need some sort of overlay logic?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

```
<div id=container class="m-auto p-2">
  <div id=theGrid class="grid grid-cols-3 divide-x divide-gray-600">
    <div id=cell1 class="px-4 h-24">
      Cell 1<br />
      <div id=thingThatSpansTwoCells class="h-4 bg-green-700 text-white col-span-2">Spans 2 Cells</div>
    </div>
    <div id=cell2 class="px-4 h-24">Cell 2</div>
    <div id=cell3 class="px-4 h-24">Cell 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `cell content to span over the dividers` I am finding it hard to understand. Can you please rephrase it or add a sample image for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your own CSS for this. To span 2 column, use `width:200%` and don't forget to account for the padding you are using:

```css
.w-200 {
  width:calc(200% + 3rem);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id=container class="m-auto p-2">
  <div id=theGrid class="grid grid-cols-3 divide-x divide-gray-600">
    <div id=cell1 class="px-4 h-24">
      Cell 1<br />
      <div id=thingThatSpansTwoCells class="bg-green-700 text-white w-200">Spans 2 Cells</div>
    </div>
    <div id=cell2 class="px-4 h-24">Cell 2</div>
    <div id=cell3 class="px-4 h-24">Cell 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Thank you.

Comment: @John If your question was answered be sure to mark this answer as 'accepted'.