# How to span single item over 2 columns in grid cell from a tailwind css grid

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, css-grid

I've got a grid using Tailwind. When spanning a grid item over 2 columns, how can I push down any items in the 2nd column?

There was a previous [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65986522/span-multiple-grid-cells-in-tailwind-css-grid), and while this does work if there are items in the 2nd column, the overlapping item will end up under it. So in my example below, how can I make Event 3 aware of Event 1 so that it moves down?

Here's my code for the grid demonstrating the issues below - https://play.tailwindcss.com/T9qGfeJDB8

Here's a screenshot if I apply a gap to the grid showing that Event 1 will span 2 grids, but will end up under the Tue Event 3.

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate out Event 1 like the other events so that it is in a separate grid item from Event 2. Then apply `grid-columns: span 2 / span 2`. Then, specify some `grid-columns` or `grid-rows` to some of the adjacent elements to reposition them back to how you'd like:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-8 grid-rows-3 gap-x-2 grid-flow-dense">
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center border border-gray-200 font-semibold">Locations</div>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center border border-gray-200 font-semibold"><span class="text-stone-400">Mon</span><span class="text-sm">1</span></div>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center border border-gray-200 font-semibold"><span class="text-stone-400">Tue</span><span class="text-sm">2</span></div>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center border border-gray-200 font-semibold"><span class="text-stone-400">Wed</span><span class="text-sm">3</span></div>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center border border-gray-200 font-semibold"><span class="text-stone-400">Thu</span><span class="text-sm">4</span></div>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center border border-gray-200 font-semibold"><span class="text-stone-400">Fri</span><span class="text-sm">5</span></div>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center border border-gray-200 font-semibold"><span class="text-stone-400">Sat</span><span class="text-sm">6</span></div>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center border border-gray-200 font-semibold"><span class="text-stone-400">Sun</span><span class="text-sm">7</span></div>

  <div class="flex items-center justify-center border border-gray-200 py-2 font-semibold row-span-2">Location 1</div>

  <div class="col-span-2 space-y-2 border border-gray-200 py-2">
    <div class="bg-red-100 pl-2">10am - 10am<br />Event 1</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="col-start-2 space-y-2 border border-gray-200 py-2">
    <div class="bg-stone-100 pl-2">6am - 1pm<br />Event 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-start-3 space-y-2 border border-gray-200 py-2">
    <div class="bg-stone-100 pl-2">6am - 1pm<br />Event 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="space-y-2 border border-gray-200 py-2">
    <div class="bg-stone-100 pl-2">6am - 1pm<br />Event 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="space-y-2 border border-gray-200 py-2">
    <div class="bg-stone-100 pl-2">6am - 1pm<br />Event 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="space-y-2 border border-gray-200 py-2">
    <div class="bg-stone-100 pl-2">6am - 1pm<br />Event 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="space-y-2 border border-gray-200 py-2">
    <div class="bg-stone-100 pl-2">6am - 1pm<br />Event 7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="space-y-2 border border-gray-200 py-2">
    <div class="bg-stone-100 pl-2">6am - 1pm<br />Event 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```